# TYPO3 9 LTS - Site configuration in multidomain environment

Tags: url, configuration, routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

Having a multidomain environment, i don't want to define the same configuration (especially route enhancers for extension records) for each domain again (each domain own e.g. a news-detail page). Is there something like a global or reusable preconfiguration possibility?

With realUrl the following was possible:

```
    'fixedPostVars' => array(
    'newsDetail' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext_news[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'enable404forInvalidAlias' => 1,
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                ),
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent'                        
            ),
        ),
    ),
    '129' => 'newsDetail',
    '130' => 'newsDetail',
    '53'  => 'newsDetail',
    '131' => 'newsDetail',
    '150' => 'newsDetail',
    '182' => 'newsDetail',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an array: DEMO to insert the values depending on domain, hope this is what you mean?

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
case 'othersite.nl':
case 'www.othersite.nl':
    $newsDetail = array(12,34,67,288);
break;
case 'website.nl':
case 'www.website.nl':
    $newsDetail = array(15,534,56,258);
break;
}
foreach($newsDetail as $value){
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT']['fixedPostVars'][$value] = 'newsDetailConfiguration';
}
```

Together with the config array this code inserts values from a simple array of numbers.

Comment: that's only another writing for a realurl configuration. JKB wants to know how this can be done in TYPO3 9, where the speaking URLs are generated by the core.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want something like a "nested" site configuration. In toplevel, i define the route enhancers for the extension records details pages. On the deeper levels, i define the usual site configuration for the domain...